# How to add user to a specific domain in Active Directory

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I need to add a specific user to a domain using New-ADUser cmdlet. 
But i don't know how to add the user to a specific domain (ex-@CCC).Which parameter should i set in order to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can point the Cmdlet at the domain controller of the domain you want to add the user to using `-Server "DomainControler.Domain.com"` parameter. This will create the user in the **default** `OU` on that domain controller unless it's told otherwise using the `-path` parameter.

If you have both domains running on a single domain control then you can just change the `OU` to that of the desired domain. `-Path "ou=mfg,dc=noam,dc=corp,dc=contoso,dc=com"`

For more help on parameters see this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx).

Comment: i saw your provided link .But from what i understood , the -path parameter may be the right parameter to add the user to a particular domain. The -Server parameter is maybe required to grant access to the user to the particular server specified .

Comment: I'm not sure on your AD setup but just using `-path` without selecting a domain control may mean you end up creating the user in the wrong domain. I.E if you have 2 or more AD forests.